# VAD to switch from listen mode to speak mode

Tags: c, audio, voice, alsa

I am attempting to turn my four-wire apartment buzzer into a VOIP phone using a raspberry pi and a custom circuit. The problem is that two way communication is not supported. I can either be listening or speaking.  I want to use a standard SIP setup with asterisk, but do VAD on the  sound output of the raspberry pi in order to send a digital signal switching the intercom to "speak mode" whenever there is a voice on the audio output.  Is there any pre-existing c function or include that listens to the ALSA mixer and throws a 1 for speech and a 0 for absence of speech with sufficiently low latency to be used in this walkie-talkie like system?

Once again, I would prefer pre-existing libraries, and because this is live, low latencies.

Comment: I believe this would be better suited in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

ALSA is a simple audio mixer, and it's interface only consists of mixer-related methods. It's meant to abstract away the hardware driver. What you will be able to do  is get the audio data from ALSA is real time, however you will need to implement your own voice activity detection.

This [question on Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2386/libraries-for-voice-activity-detection-not-speech-recognition) has a few good suggestions for libraries and codec implementations to get you started.

Comment: I asked the question here because I believe that interfacing with ALSA will be fairly simple, but am not confident in my ability to code a VAD algorithm, so I am looking for a preexisting library if it exists.  I saw the thread you linked to, but none of the linked code looked like what I needed.  I know there are preexisting libraries, but I don't know which ones are closest to what I want, or how to go about modifying them, so that's why I asked in dsp.

Comment: Would you like it migrated back?